# import fl.data.DataProvider; is not working in Adobe CS4

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, adobe

How can I use import `fl.data.DataProvider;` in Adobe CS4. When I try to import it showing

`1172: Definition fl.controls could not be found.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the *fl* library will not show up in your IDE until you drag a component that actually uses it (in this case, a component that uses a data provider) into your library.

you can manually add *fl* to your class path if you want so that it's always there, but it's not more useful since you'll need the target component in your library during compile time anyway.  it's by design.  components have a built-in "Component Shim" that exposes its code package to your IDE.