# Cannot import mx packages

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, adobe, mxml, mxmlc

In the Below action script file there is an error saying cannot import mx.controls.Label,
I am compiling this through command line on,linux and the environment variable path is set where flex is installed ,how to resolve this

```
package {

 import mx.controls.Label;

 public class Test
 {
    public function Test()
    {
      Alert.show("Test");
    }
  }
}
```

**Edit:**

```
       [root@localhost tmp]# mxmlc Test.as 
      Loading configuration file /opt/flex/frameworks/flex-config.xml
     /tmp/Test.as: Warning: This compilation unit did not have a factoryClass         specified in Frame metadata to load the configured runtime shared libraries. To compile without runtime shared libraries either set the -static-link-runtime-shared-libraries option to true or remove the -runtime-shared-libraries option.

    /tmp/Test.swf (466 bytes)
```

Comment: recent similar post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224044/import-fl-data-dataprovider-is-not-working-in-adobe-cs4/4225181#4225181

Comment: But not the same problem/Solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you need to add the Flex source (or SWC) to the library path of your command line argument.  Look at the [library-path](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_14.html) command line argument.

I'm not entirely sure what you mean when you say "the environment variable path is set where flex is installed".  What environment variable?  How is it used?  Perhaps you'll want to show us the command line you are using and/or the batch file?

Comment: I meant that the path where mxmlc resides is included in the bash file .please see the edited question

Comment: @Rajeev We are moving beyond my Linux experience here.  The bat file didn't help me solve your problem.  Even if mxmlc is known, you still need to tell mxmlc where to find the Flex code or compiled SWCs.  Do that using the library-path command line argument.